# how to center a label through style

Tags: asp.net, html, label

I would like to center a label using STYLE not through CSS.

```
<label style="color:Red; vertical-align:middle;"> TEXT </label>
```

does not work, does anyone have any ideas
thanks

Comment: ...`style` **is** CSS

Comment: @Doorknob I think OP was meaning *"not through an external CSS file or element"*. I hope so.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `text-align:center;`?

Comment: OP, Are you trying to do a vertical or horizontal centering ? In both cases you'll probably have to google and work for your specific problem. And it will be a little more complex for a vertical centering.

Comment: yes its a vertical center, and yes i meant "not through an external CSS file or element".

Comment: text-align:center works didnt realise you could do that thanks for all relies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily like this ...

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <label style="color:Red;">TEXT</label>
</div>
```

This also use CSS but in the same HTML file, you can't do what you want without CSS..
Hope this will help you